# Exception coming with HttpUrlConnection in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying the following code to post a json.

It has worked once but now it is throwing the following Exception message: "failed to connect to /xx.xx.xx.xx (port XXXXX) after 5000ms"

What is the problem here?

```
public void sendToDp(PayloadEntity pEntity) {

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(PreferenceHelper.getInstance().getBaseUrl());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(pEntity.getJsonString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        listener.onReceive(responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK, pEntity);
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        listener.onReceive(false, pEntity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        listener.onReceive(false, pEntity);
    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding the stacktrace:

03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.41.66.248 (port 11890) after 5000ms
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:139)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:56)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.onReceive(QueueManager.java:97)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.NetworkHelper.sendToDp(NetworkHelper.java:71)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager$LooperThread$1.handleMessage(QueueManager.java:129)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.QueueManager.startUpload(QueueManager.java:62)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at network.Logger.logUpdates(Logger.java:59)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at service.PullHelper.init(PullHelper.java:61)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at service.SyncService.onHandleIntent(SyncService.java:26)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-02 17:22:34.793 24578-24758/com.vkc.main W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: I know its funny but have you added any break point near connection object configuration or near output stream operations??

Comment: Are you sure your server and port which you are trying to connect is up and running??

Comment: Are you doing this on the UI Thread?

Comment: Try and simulate this POST request using [Advanced Rest API client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). If you are getting an error here too then it is mostly a server side issue.

Comment: I am doing this in a background thread.. the request is working from Advanced Rest Api CLient... It was working with this code as well, but suddenly it stopped working ...

Comment: Can you post your complete log

Comment: Have added the stacktrace to the question... SocketTimeout Exception is coming... any thoughts why this has started happening suddenly?

Comment: Is your device internet connection fast enough? It should be mostly because of a slow connection, try increasing your timeout or don't give any timeout and try once.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a better http library, like **Volley**, it's faster to run and **simpler to debug** than HttpUrlConnection.

Your code will be look like:

```
JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlLink, new JsonObject(pEntity.getJsonString()), new Response.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    //RESPONSE
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                   //ERROR
                }
            });
```

[Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/request.html)

[About Volley be faster](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-library-to-make-HTTP-calls-from-Java-Android)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your app cannot get through the network and access the URL. The problem may be:

- Your network connection is offline.
- The site which you are trying to access is down.
- You are facing either firewall or proxy issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing java.net.SocketTimeoutException because you have set connection time out to some value
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

System try to establish connection to Your Url till the timeout value.If it fail to establish the connection with in the time you have set it will throw the "SocketTimeoutException"

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem coming in your case(as I was facing) because your service is running on localhost(failed to connect to /10.41.66.248 (port 11890) after 5000ms ). I mean on local network and you are trying to connect from outer network(Like mobile data). But local network doesn't give access to other network just because some security reasons.
**So connect your device to local wi-fi network(same localhost internet connection), then run your app.**

Hope this will solve your problem....